# Debugging in Netbeans8.0

Tags: netbeans, gdbserver

I am not able to debug in Netbean by using gdb server. I am using Windows 7.

1. the gdb server has been started successfully and waiting to the connection,
2. I just select 'debug->attach debugger'
3. look for 'gdbserver' process , which is currentlly running gdb server.(v-1.9.0 pro)
4. then click OK button. below error will come out:

```
'C:\\ST-LINK_gdbserver\\ST-LINK_gdbserver.exe': can't read symbols: File format not recognized
```

Anyone can give some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I  switched gdbserver to gdb.exe running from Cygwin forlder, but it popup below in the netbean attach debugger dialog:

```
"Connecting to gdb failed: Directory C:\cygwin\usr\bin doesnt exist"
```